# Java's Calendar.getInstance().getTime() equivalent in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, java, date

`Calendar.getInstance().getTime()` is a method which returns a date object in ***Java***.

This method creates an object like this:

```
{
    "date": 12,
    "day": 2,
    "hours": 8,
    "minutes": 51,
    "month": 5,
    "seconds": 22,
    "time": 1528786282990,
    "timezoneOffset": -120,
    "year": 118
}
```

I work in a team that is developing a mobile app. In the middle they decided to make a web app version as well. So I'm using React.

The main problem is, this is a Java-specific method (I think), the whole mobile app is developed in Java, and I'm using JavaScript.

My suggestion was to just take the `"time": 1528786282990` and then parse it in both apps. But the main app developer told me there would be a lot of changes in the mobile app if we did it this way.

How can I recreate this object, other than manually? Or maybe we should still switch to using just the `time` property?

But if there is a method in JavaScript, which creates a date object like this one, this would be perfect.

I know there is the [getTime method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/getTime) in JavaScript, but it just gives me the time, like this: `1528879344570`. I can parse most of it manually, but date, month and things like this would be complicated.

Comment: Unfortunately, there isn't any. You manually need to construct the object yourself. BTW, using [MomentJS](https://momentjs.com/) may ease your work upto some extent.

Comment: "This method creates an object like this:" That object is a `java.util.Date`. It is a pretty bad idea to rely upon the values of those fields, since their values depend upon the default time zone of the JVM on which it is run - a `j.u.Date` is simply a wrapper around a long timestamp.

Comment: Considering possible future updates, would it be better to switch the whole app to just the timestamps, or is building the object manually safe and stable?

Comment: @alex.iron using timestamps is what I would do.

Comment: Ok thank you. Would someone like to add an answer?

Comment: Doesn’t `new Date()` give you that in JavaScript like in Java? I know that they are completely different languages with completely different libraries.

Comment: Response from the console a second ago `Date 2018-06-13T08:55:31.574Z`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a `Date` object:

```
var date = new Date(); // creates a Date object with the current date and time, in the local timezone
```

You can then use its various methods (refer [here](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_obj_date.asp) for a list) to get the desired values. For example, you can get the month (in range 0–11) like this:

```
date.getMonth();
```

Comment: This might be the way to do it

Answer (score 0):

You can have year, monthIndex, day, hours, minutes, seconds and milliseconds; part of it using:

`new Date()`

So it would be something like:

```
var x = new Date(Calendar); //It gives you the date in a way js can work with
```

Offset:

```
x.getTimezoneOffset() //returns UTC in minutes
```

Comment: In order to work it in js, yes.
When something like offset is required just call for it.

Comment: Please add some formatting to your answer to make it more readable.

Comment: The OP probably needs `new Date(calendar.time)`, where *calendar* is a *Calendar* instance. Also, *getTimezoneOffset* returns the host timezone offset, since javascript Dates do not have one (they only have a time value and some methods for calculating year, month, day, etc.).

Comment: @RobG I could be wrong but 'Calendar' doesnt have the property time, when getting a date from server to manage it on js i use 'new Date()' with the var inside.

Comment: The object in the OP has a *time* property. Presumably that object was created by `Calendar.getInstance().getTime()`, it's that object's *time* property that seems to be relevant. Passing an object to the Date constructor is covered in [*ECMA-262*](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/8.0/#sec-date-value), I don't think the object in the OP is suitable.